# How can I setTemplate for catalog product view?

Tags: php, magento, overriding

I am overriding the catalog product view page. I have to set my own template file, rather then `view.phtml`.

```
<catalog>       
    <rewrite>      
        <product_view>
            COM_MODULE_Block_Catalog_Product_View
        </product_view>
    </rewrite>
</catalog>
```

So how can I do this? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit your config.xml file

```
<blocks>
  <catalog>
     <rewrite>
       <product_view>yournamespace_modulename_block_View</product_view>
     </rewrite>
  </catalog>
</blocks>
```

and create  View.php  file in namespace/Module/Block/View.php

```
class Namespace_ModuleName_Block_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
{
  // Your Functions 
}
```